# Getting the actual URL, best practices for this case

Tags: php, javascript, html

i need to insert the actual URL on this link:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=**MY_URL**&t=<?php echo($title); ?>" target="blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

What method will be the best? Thanks!

Comment: `location.href` in JavaScript for the url (without the last "/")

Comment: Do you mean the URL of the current page?

Comment: @JCOC611 how can i insert it on the context?

Comment: Yes, best to use JS as PHP may be mucked up if its in an include.

Comment: @DomingoSL then I'd agree with thedom's answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the superglobal `$_SERVER` array ;-)

```
<?php
$myURL = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
```

and your link will be...

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo($myURL); ?>&t=<?php echo($title); ?>" target="blank">Share on Facebook</a>
```

// **EDIT**:
`$myURL` should be `urlencode()`d and check for protocol -->

```
<?php
$protocol = 'http://';

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
  $protocol = 'https://';
}

$myURL = urlencode($protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

Comment: $myURL must be URL-encoded before inserting it into the link. The schema is not necessarily http (it might be https). $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] should be validated.